# Change Footer Color in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, footer

Help. I'm new to wordpress and I'd like to change this basic code by adding a yellow background color.

```
<hr />
<div id="footer">
<p>
Powered by <a href="http://wordpress.org/&#034;   
title="WordPress">WordPress</a>
<br /><a href="feed:<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>">Entries (RSS)</a>
and <a href="feed:<?php bloginfo('comments_rss2_url'); ?>">Comments (RSS)   
</a>.
</p>
```

Where would I add this change, and how would I go about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a footer.php you can add any class names or information to the footer if you would like.

You could also edit the style.css file to change the footer in there.

footer { background-color: yellow; }

Comment: Would adding this code to the footer.php file override the information in the style.css file if there is a footer section in it?

Comment: Overriding depends on the sequence of compilation. If new CSS snippet is present after main style.css then it'll be used, provided it has no conflicts with other CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php write following:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'myFooterColorCb' );
function myFooterColorCb () {
 echo '<style type="text/css">#footer {background-color: #ffcc33;}<style>';
}
```

This will color the element `#footer` with `#ffcc33` by adding a small style element in the `<head></head>` of header.php

Comment: Does the placement of the code matter with respect to the wordpress code above? What's the difference between placing the code in the functions.php file or style.css file vs the footer.php file?

Comment: The code in function.php will be compiled in right sequence and if you mention a priority to the add_action then it can be printed after theme's CSS files. As WordPress theme gets updated, so using any of the methods in a child theme will do.